# Is there any way to solve issue of local storage in server side rendering on angular version 8?

Tags: angular, local-storage, angular8

Actually, the problem is when I am trying to run my application using ssr (server-side render) then i faced error like "localStorage is not defined"

```
ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
    at FunctionsService.sendHeaders (E:\www\nginx\html\frontend-v2\dist\server\main.js:192493:88)
    at new TemplateService (E:\www\nginx\html\frontend-v2\dist\server\main.js:39149:39)
    at _createClass (E:\www\nginx\html\frontend-v2\dist\server\main.js:71169:20)
    at _createProviderInstance (E:\www\nginx\html\frontend-v2\dist\server\main.js:71130:26)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (E:\www\nginx\html\frontend-v2\dist\server\main.js:71077:21)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (E:\www\nginx\html\frontend-v2\dist\server\main.js:72163:16)
    at resolveDep (E:\www\nginx\html\frontend-v2\dist\server\main.js:72694:45)
    at createClass (E:\www\nginx\html\frontend-v2\dist\server\main.js:72547:32)
    at createDirectiveInstance (E:\www\nginx\html\frontend-v2\dist\server\main.js:72358:22)
    at createViewNodes (E:\www\nginx\html\frontend-v2\dist\server\main.js:83638:38)
```

**Sample Code**

```
import { Injectable,PLATFORM_ID,Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import {ToastyService, ToastyConfig, ToastyComponent, ToastOptions, ToastData} from 'ng2-toasty';
import {Subject, Observable, Subscription} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable()
export class FunctionsService {

constructor(
           @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platform: Object,
           private toastyService:ToastyService, private toastyConfig: ToastyConfig
) { }

 sendHeaders():any{
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platform)) {
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers = headers.set('Content-Type','application/json').set('Authorization',localStorage.getItem('token')).set('Accept','application/json'); 
        return headers;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: `localStorage` & `sessionStorage` are part of the browser. it's not related to any angular version

Comment: Please post your service code...

Comment: Yes, I know that but I need a solution for ssr.

Answer (score 0):

As per [angular universal Gotcha's](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/docs/gotchas.md)

> If you need to use them, consider limiting them to only your client
>   and wrapping them situationally. You can use the Object injected using
>   the PLATFORM_ID token to check whether the current platform is browser
>   or server.

Comment: It's hard to tell what exactly didn't worked for you, as tried with angular ssr exmaple(https://angular.io/guide/universal) and was successful in setting local storage... Can you create a basic github repo via which we can see the exact issue